# Can't get searchBook method for specific donor

Tags: java

This program's goal is input book's title, donor, number of chapters, and location.   From there, the user puts their input for this following prompt: "For search enter donor’s name: ________".
I am able to get all that information as an output. However, i cannot seem to figure out how to narrow down the results to just ONE donor. Instead, my program prints out all of the donor's listed in the entries.
I have listed my program thus far below as well as my sample out and my desired output.

Thank you!

```
  package Books;
    
    import java.util.Scanner;
    
    public class Books {
              
            String title;
            String donatedBy;
            int numChapters;
            String bookLocation;
    
            void Book(){
    
                title="ava Programming";
    
                donatedBy="James Bond";
    
                numChapters=25;
                
                bookLocation = "A-007";
    
            }
    
            Books(String title, String donatedBy, int numChapters, String bookLocation){
    
                 this.title=title;
                 this.donatedBy=donatedBy;
                 this.bookLocation=bookLocation;
                   if(numChapters<1){
                     this.numChapters=25;
                    }
                    else{
                        this.numChapters=numChapters;
                    }
                }
                public String getTitle() {
                    return title;
                }
                public String getDonatedBy() {
                    return donatedBy;
                }
                public int getNumChapters() {
                    return numChapters;
                }
                public void setDonatedBy(String donatedBy) {
                    this.donatedBy = donatedBy;
                }
                public void setNumChapters(int numChapters) {
                    this.numChapters = numChapters;
                }
                public void setTitle(String title) {
                    this.title = title;
}
                public void printDetails(){
                    System.out.print("Title: \t"+title+" \nDonor: \t"+donatedBy+" \nChapters: "+numChapters + "\nLocation: " + bookLocation);
                }
                public static void main(String[] args) {
                    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
                    System.out.print("Enter number of Books: ");
                    int num = scanner.nextInt();
                    scanner.nextLine();
                    Books[] books = new Books[num];
    
                    for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {
                        System.out.print("Enter the title: ");
                        String title = scanner.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter the donor: ");
                        String donor = scanner.nextLine();
                        System.out.print("Enter the number of chapters: ");
                        int chaps = scanner.nextInt();

                        
                        scanner.nextLine();
                        books[i] =new Books(title, donor, chaps, bookLocation);
                    }
                    
                    boolean flag=false;
    
                    for(int i=0; i<books.length;i++){
                        Books b=books[i];
                        System.out.print("\n\nBook "+(i+1)+": \n");
                        b.printDetails();
                        
                        if (b.getDonatedBy().equals("Daisy")){
                            flag=true;
                        
        
                }
                scanner.close();
            }
```

Comment: I know that i need to create a searchBook method in order to get the user input for donor, but i am not sure where to put that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that this is what you need to do:

```java
System.out.print("For search enter donor’s name: ");
//scanner.nextLine(); //Sometimes .nextLine() won't work, so if this code doesn't work uncomment this line and it should work. 
String donor = scanner.nextLine();

for(int i=0; i<books.length;i++){
     Books b=books[i];
  
     if (b.getDonatedBy().equalsIgnoreCase(donor)){ //if the user input matches the donor name, do the following
        System.out.print("\n\nBook "+(i+1)+": \n");
        b.printDetails(); //you're printing if the user input matches the donor
        flag=true;
     } 
}
```

For the part about the getting book location, use this:

```java
System.out.print("Enter the book location: ");
scanner.nextLine(); //Like I said, .nextLine() won't work sometimes
bookLocation = scanner.nextLine();
```

Comment: The "donor's name" solution worked - Thank you very much! I still cannot manage to get the location to show up in the output. Is there anything else i can try?

Comment: @Connie try removing the extra `scanner.nextLine()` i have in my code for the book location in the original answer. Also, if my answer solved your problem, make sure to click the green check mark to mark this question as answered.

Comment: When I order the code like this: `System.out.print("Enter the book location: "); scanner.nextLine();
bookLocation = scanner.next();`
              I get an output for location but it repeats "B-007" for all locations. When i delete the `scanner.nextLine()` it gives me no output.

Comment: @Connie to fix that issue do this: `String bookLocation = scanner.next();`. That should work.

Answer (score 0):

heloo,
I hope i don't say something stupid, but if i understand that this line "b.printDetails();" it prints out the details  you want, it should not be under that if clause? "b.getDonatedBy().match.." because only then, you want to print the details.

Answer (score 0):

you can just add the `b.printDetails();` inside your if as below:

```
System.out.println("For search enter donor’s name: Daisy");

for(int i=0; i<books.length;i++){
     Books b=books[i];
     // place you print details inside the if statement
     if (b.getDonatedBy().equals("Daisy")){
        System.out.print("\n\nBook "+(i+1)+": \n");
        b.printDetails();
        flag=true;
     } 
}
```

Comment: That worked - Thanks! Do you know why my program is not picking up the location input from the user in the output?

Comment: Also, the print statement "System.out.println("For search enter donor’s name: Daisy");" does not show up when the program is complied. Could you provide some clarity as to why that is?

Comment: use this  `System.out.println("\nFor search enter donor’s name: Daisy");` this is just a to print message

Comment: @Connie use String `bookLocation = scanner.next();` to get bookLocation