# How to invoke a searchBook method to find books donated as donatedBy data attribute

Tags: java

I am trying to add a searchBook method that finds all the books donated as donatedBy data attribute.  I have to call the searchBook method to find the books donated by “Daisy”. I am having trouble finding out where to put the searchBook method so that I can call it later when I get the user input for "donor".

I have provided a snippet of my code for your convenience.
Thank you very much!

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Enter number of Books: ");
            int N = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();
            Books[] books = new Books[N];

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
                System.out.print("Enter the title: ");
                String title = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter the donor: ");
                String donor = scanner.nextLine();
                System.out.print("Enter the number of chapters: ");
                int chaps = scanner.nextInt();
                System.out.print("Enter the book location: ");
                bookLocation = scanner.nextLine();  
                
                scanner.nextLine();
                books[i] =new Books(title, donor, chaps, bookLocation);
            }
            
            boolean flag=false;
          
            
          System.out.print("\nFor search enter donor’s name: ");
          String donor = scanner.nextLine();

          for(int i=0; i<books.length;i++){
               Books b=books[i];
          
               if (b.getDonatedBy().equalsIgnoreCase(donor)){ //if the user input matches the donor name, do the following
                  System.out.print("\nBook "+(i+1)+": \n");
                  b.printDetails(); //you're printing if the user input matches the donor
                  flag=true;
               } 
          } 

            if (flag){
                System.out.println("\nTask Complete. ");
            }
            scanner.close();
        }
}
```

Comment: Unclear. You have the code to search. Do you just want to move that into a separate function?

Comment: Yes, I am required to have a method that searches for all the books donated by the name the user inputs. I have the code, but I am unsure where to put the method and how to call that method to find the books donated by the user input.

Comment: You could put it into whatever class the `main` function is in and maybe make it `static`. For example: `public static boolean search(Book[] books, String donor) { .... }`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't get searchBook method for specific donor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66910057/cant-get-searchbook-method-for-specific-donor)

Comment: I am still confused on where to put the "searchBook ()" method in my code in order to find the books donated by a specific donor. Could you provide more clarity?

Answer (score 0):

## Write a class

When you have stuff to do (methods) and state (variables, data) on which to operate those methods, define a class.

You need a class named something like `BookRepository` that loads book information from user inputs, files, database, etc. Call on an instance (object) of that class to both load and search the books.

Your `BookRepository` class would have an `addBook` method. That method adds the passed `Book` object to a collection of `Book` type.

Your `BookRepository` class offers a method `findByDonor` that returns a collection of `Book` objects matching the passed donor name.

## Example code

Define the `Book` class as a [record](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395) in Java 16 and later. Or write a conventional class in older versions of Java.

```java
package work.basil.books;

public record Book(String title , String location , int countChapters, String donor )
{
}
```

Define the `BookRepository` class with 4 methods: one constructor, two methods for adding books either one at a time or by adding an array of books, and one query method named `findByDonor`.

```java
package work.basil.books;

import java.util.*;

public class BookRepository
{
    private Set < Book > books;

    public BookRepository ( )
    {
        this.books = new HashSet <>();
        // … load persisted books from file storage, or database server, etc.
    }

    public void addBook ( final Book book )
    {
        this.books.add( book );
    }

    public void addBooks ( final Book[] books )
    {
        Set < Book > booksSet = Set.of( books );
        this.books.addAll( booksSet );
    }

    public Set < Book > findByDonor ( final String donor )
    {
        Set < Book > hits = new HashSet <>();
        for ( Book book : books )
        {
            if ( book.donor().equalsIgnoreCase( donor ) )
            {
                hits.add( book );
            }
        }
        return Set.copyOf( hits ); // Return nonmodifiable set.
    }
}
```

Write a little demo app to use those classes.

```java
package work.basil.books;

import java.util.Set;

public class App
{
    public static void main ( String[] args )
    {
        App app = new App();
        app.demo();
    }

    private void demo ( )
    {
        BookRepository bookRepository = new BookRepository();
        Book[] books = new Book[] {
                new Book( "Thinking In Java" , "D3" , 12 , "Alice" ) ,
                new Book( "Java Concurrency In Practice" , "D3" , 15 , "Bob" ) ,
                new Book( "Road to Serfdom" , "L2" , 7 , "Carol" ) ,
                new Book( "The Real Crash" , "L2" , 7 , "Bob" )
        };
        bookRepository.addBooks( books );
        Set < Book > booksDonatedByBob = bookRepository.findByDonor( "Bob" );

        System.out.println( "Count of books donated by Bob: " + booksDonatedByBob.size() );
        System.out.println( "booksDonatedByBob = " + booksDonatedByBob );
    }
}
```

Notice how this collection of classes follows the [Separation of Concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) principle. The `Book` class is focused on representing each book we are tracking in the real world, nothing more, no concern with collecting books, no concern for interacting with users on a console. The `BookRepository` class tracks a collection of the `Book` objects, and knows how search for books, nothing more, no concern about the integrity of how to best represent a book, no concern for interacting with users on a console. You should write another class to contain your code for interacting with user via console to gather entered-data. The `App` class puts those classes together to accomplish something useful.

For your schoolwork assignment, it would seem you are expected to use arrays. That is fine. You can use the same class structure as above but with arrays rather than collections like `Set`. Using arrays will be a bit more work, but is doable.